# Combining lists in Lisp, only using first and cons

Tags: recursion, lisp

I'm working on an assignment and I need to combine two lists, but we're only allowed to use the following functions:

```
cons(e,L)
first(L)
rest(L)
```

I've been trying to figure out how to do this recursively using only those functions for hours now but have no idea. We're supposed to use notation similar to this:

```
find(L, k) is
    NULL    if L = NULL
or first(L) if first(L) = k
or find(rest(L), k)
```

Any suggestions? Thank you!!

Comment: What does "combine" mean, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

If combine means appending two lists, then try following pseudo code:

```
append(a,b) =
  if nil(a) then b
  else cons(first(a),append(rest(a),b))
```